# Mosquitto inflight_messages = 1, but got more than 1 message simultaneously

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I've set `max_inflight_messages` to 1, but after stress test, my client got multiple simultaneous messages.

Does I misunderstood something? I thought "in-order delivery of messages" means every message should sent through PUBLISH, PUBREC, PUBREL, PUBCOMP, then next message.

Extracted `mosquitto.log`

```
1488858217: Sending PUBLISH to client (d0, q2, r0, m669, 'test/topic', ... (7 bytes))
1488858217: Sending PUBLISH to client (d0, q1, r0, m670, 'test/topic', ... (7 bytes))
1488858217: Sending PUBLISH to client (d0, q2, r0, m671, 'test/topic', ... (7 bytes))
1488858217: Sending PUBLISH to client (d0, q2, r0, m672, 'test/topic', ... (7 bytes))
1488858217: Sending PUBLISH to client (d0, q2, r0, m673, 'test/topic', ... (7 bytes))
1488858217: Received PUBREC from client (Mid: 669)
1488858217: Sending PUBREL to client (Mid: 669)
1488858217: Received PUBACK from client (Mid: 670)
1488858217: Received PUBREC from client (Mid: 671)
1488858217: Sending PUBREL to client (Mid: 671)
1488858217: Received PUBREC from client (Mid: 672)
1488858217: Sending PUBREL to client (Mid: 672)
1488858217: Received PUBREC from client (Mid: 673)
1488858217: Sending PUBREL to client (Mid: 673)
```

Thanks

This question is also post to [mosquitto/issues/393](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/393)

Comment: That log output seams to show all the messages were delivered in order.

Comment: Sorry I used a misleading topic

Comment: In my case, I want to ensure the client only handle one mqtt message. MQTT client may short of memory to handle lots of mqtt message simultaneously to save their status.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your QoS for your Mqtt Broker is at level 2. This ensures that all messages are received exactly once, but this can also greatly affect your performance as it can take a long time to receive the messages.

https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels